# Nvidia Graphics Monitor Error

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, windows-vista

After I had downloaded Windows 7 on to my HP Pavilion DV6000 I deleted all my files on my computer, as well as the "Windows Old" on the local C: drive. I then downloaded some games that worked fine when I had Windows Vista, but they did not work anymore. It said I needed a better graphics card and to upgrade the Nvidia driver.

So I checked and found out that I did not have Nvidia on my PC anymore since I had deleted it, so I went to the Nvidia website and downloaded it. But when it still didn't work I uninstalled it and contacted HP. I got some help and explained the problem and was told to do the exact same thing that I already had done, download Nvidia. So I figured that, that was no help so I gave up until I remembered that I had deleted all my old files included Nvidia that was already installed on my computer when I got it. So I did a second attempt at downloading Nvidia GeForce, but it still didn't work. So I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice about how to fix my the problem.

I also have another problem. I can't connect an external monitor to my computer. When I had Windows Vista it worked, but when I got Windows 7 it seems like my computer does not detect the monitor. I have also checked the Device Manager where it says that the standard VGA adapter is working fine.

I've also checked on many different websites and followed the instructions, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I would use HP drivers. Because many vendors customize their drivers for their hardware. The Vista drivers usually work in Windows 7. If they don't I would try here for a customized driver. [laptopvideo2go](http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/drivers)

Comment: i certainly wouuld not use them. not when it comes to graphics cards. and certainly not outdated graphic drivers for an older operating system. nVidia has the most up-to-date drivers for your graphics card, not HP. and this 3rd party website looks like a scam to me anyways! "All drivers are priced at wholesale prices!"

Comment: Not necessarily true Molly. I have seen plenty of laptops that would not even boot with the stock nVidia drivers and required the OEM's drivers.And using the Vista drivers really should work, in most cases, and is what Microsoft generally recommends, as well as the OEMs.

Answer (score 1):

there are different drivers available at nVidia, make sure you get the correct driver for your model and operating system.

look for **Geforce Go 7 Series (Notebook)** and the correct operating system (Windows 7 32-bit or Windows 7 64-bit)

Comment: I have let nVidia chose my driver for me so that i will get the correct one. (There is a program there that choses the best suited for my computer)

But thanks anyway.
King regards Emile T O

Comment: Perhaps the automated tool is broken and it would be better to do it manually?